# The dll extension file for PHP 5.5.16

Tags: php, apache

Sorry, if question is not correct.

I compiled **Apache PHP** with a offered packages and extensions. After checked installed and enabled extensions(*curl, gd2, mcrypt, sockets*) :  `echo phpinfo ();`

But in the logs says that **dll** is not found for extension:

> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_curl.dll
>
> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll
>
> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_mcrypt.dll
>
> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_sockets.dll
>
> PHP Warning: Cannot load module 'pdo_cassandra' because required
>   module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   Current version of PHP: **5.5.16** 
>   **CentOS 6.5**

What solutions have for this? Where I can give this **dll** files? Maybe someone could share them?

Comment: DLL is the shared library format used by Microsoft Windows. You are using Linux. There's something terribly weird in your set up...

Comment: Have you copied a php.ini file from Windows to your Linux server? As Álvaro says, Linux does not use DLL files.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install the php-pdo package. The PDO parent package needs to be installed so the pdo_cassandra can do its thing. [How to install](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php)

Comment: Sorry, I use CentOS 6.5. php_curl.dll and else will install together PDO?